How to parse text file with headers that have multiple lines in Python
I have a dataset that contains several lines of headers. I want to plot out the data, with Time on the x-axis and Sum(cvTop) in the y-axis. The .out file (Which contains data) looks like this (Edited):
All solute fluxes and cumulative solute fluxes are positive into the region
   Time         cvTop        cvBot      Sum(cvTop)   Sum(cvBot)     cvCh0        cvCh1         cTop        cRoot         cBot        cvRoot    Sum(cvRoot)  Sum(cvNEql) TLevel      cGWL        cRunOff   Sum(cRunOff)    (cv(i),    Sum(cv(i)), i=1,NObs)
    [T]        [M/L2/T]     [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]       [M/L2]       [M/L2]      [M/L2]        [M/L3]      [M/L3]        [M/L3]      [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]       [M/L2]              [M/L3]        [M/L2]      [M/L3]      [M/L2/T]      [M/L2]
    0.0010  0.00000E+00 -0.15405E-02  0.00000E+00 -0.15405E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29945E+03  0.00000E+00  0.15410E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00       1  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29385E+03  0.29385E+00 -0.54338E+04 -0.54338E+01 -0.16439E+05 -0.16439E+02 -0.64983E+04 -0.64983E+01
    0.0020  0.00000E+00  0.43077E-02  0.00000E+00  0.27673E-05  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.30023E+03  0.00000E+00  0.15410E+04  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00       2  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.00000E+00  0.29437E+03  0.58822E+00 -0.43086E+04 -0.97424E+01 -0.93670E+04 -0.25806E+02 -0.70594E+04 -0.13558E+02

And currently, I have a python code below which I am stuck on:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Load time series data from a file
file_path = r'C:\Program Files\Hydrus-1D\Examples\Direct\Attempt10\solute1.out'
# Replace 'your_file_name.csv' with the actual name of your file

# Assuming your data file has two columns: Date and Value
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=['Time', 'Sum(cvBot)'], index_col='Time')


# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(data)
plt.title('Time Series Plot')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

I'm a bit new to python programming, so I appreciate any pointers or help. Thank you!

if your multiple lines of headers stops you thats relatively simple: df = pd.read_csv(“filename.txt”,sep=”x”, header=1)

can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Apologies for not replying soon enough, I've copied the data from the .out file as text. At the moment I've changed the read_csv line to "data = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"], index_col="Time", skiprows=[1])", but it's giving me ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Sum(cvBot)', 'Time'].

You can pass skiprows with the index of the rows to skip. Rows are counted starting from 0:
df = pd.read_csv(
    file_path,
    usecols=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"],
    index_col="Time",
    skiprows=[0, 1, 3],
    sep="\s+",
)

Also: please do not post image as data. Copy the first few lines as text into your question.

Thank you @Code Different, I've just copy and pasted the data into my question. The problem was in my separator! I've used "data = pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=["Time", "Sum(cvBot)"], index_col="Time", skiprows=[1], sep = " ")" and it worked for this data. Thanks for the help!
